# Media files disappear after i push to heroku

Tags: python, django

I've created a new Django project that users can update images, and the images are being stored in `/images` dir, here is my setting part about it :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images/')
MEDIA_URL = '/Images/'
```

and here is the DB setting part I am using with Heroku

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
SQL_ALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

here is the website `https://fostania-web-app.herokuapp.com/`, u can see it the image slider that fails every time I push.

Any suggestions about this !?

Comment: As the Heroku docs make clear, the filesystem is ephemeral and anything stored there will not persist between dyno restarts. You need to store uploaded files somewhere permanent, such as Amazon S3.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, you know any ALTS for amazon s3  that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I just needed to use a cloud storage services because Heroku can't save files ... I picked Amazon web services .. here is a good step by step guide :
[How to setup Amazon S3 with django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html)